# How to get textbox values

Tags: javascript, jstl

```
 <form:form method="get" action="" onsubmit="return matchPassword();" id="myform" commandName="users">
 <ul>


        <li>
            <form:label path="password" id="newPwd"><spring:message code="label.password"/></form:label>
            <form:input path="password"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <form:label path="password" id="RePwd"><spring:message code="label.password"/></form:label>
            <form:input path="password"/>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" class="btn" value="<spring:message code="label.adduser"/>"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form:form>
```

As given i have two input boxes for password. now i want to compare whether value of both the boxes are same using java script.
How can i get values from these text boxes, Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.matchPassword = function(){
    return document.getElementById('newPwd').value == document.getElementById('RePwd').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bashed this out - haven't tested it, but it should put you in the right direction.

```
    var newPwd = document.getElementById('newPwd').value;
    var RePwd = document.getElementById('RePwd').value;

    if (newPwd != RePwd)
    {
       alert("Passwords Don't match");
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing called `getElementById`. Since the user seems a newbie in JS, avoid giving code that may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var txt1 = document.getElementById('newPwd');
var firstPwd = txt1.value;

var txt2 = document.getElementById('RePwd');
var rePwd = txt2.value;
```

And then compare the two variables `firstPwd` and `rePwd` for equality:

```
if (firstPwd == rePwd)
 // proceed
else
 // notify error!
```